# Redirect public site to another one but allow administrators to access the old site

Tags: admin, redirect

I have two WordPress sites and I'm closing one of those sites and want all traffic redirected to the second website.

If possible I would like to have the first to be viewed only by administrators only. Can this be done?

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Comment: How much traffic do you expect to hit the old site that would need to be redirected away? Spinning up WordPress just to send the majority of requests elsewhere is kind of a bummer. I would consider just 301 redirecting the whole domain and moving the site elsewhere under password protection.

Comment: Not much traffic.. Just about 300-400 hits a month..i like the idea of doing a complete domain redirect and dumping the old site as a sub domain with password protect  in another domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to catch this on [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) or during [`parse_request`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_request) / [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Whitelist some pages like the login or your IP addresses otherwise you'll get locked out should you sign-off.

Adding 301 to the [`wp_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) will help [search engines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).

```
// NOTE: This code has not been tested

function wpse12302015_check_user_status()
{
    // a user with admin privileges? - forget about it
    if(current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        return;
    }

    // whitelist some pages 
    if( is_page( 'login' )  )
    {
        return;
    }

    // send them off to the new website using the current request
    $url = 'http://www.example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    wp_redirect( $url, 301 ); // Moved Permanently
    exit();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse12302015_check_user_status' );
```

The *`template_redirect`* doesn't look like it hits the *`login`* events.

**Login Events**

- [`init`]
- [`widgets_init`]
- [`wp_loaded`]
- [`admin_init`]
- [`wp_authenticate`]
- [`wp_login`]
- [`shutdown`]

**Front End Events**

- [`init`]
- [`widgets_init`]
- [`wp_loaded`]
- [`parse_request`]
- [`pre_get_posts`]
- **[`template_redirect`]**

**Admin Events**

- [`init`]
- [`widgets_init`]
- [`wp_loaded`]
- [`admin_menu`]
- [`admin_init`]
- [`wp_print_scripts`]
- [`admin_head`]
- [`admin_footer`]
- [`shutdown`]

Comment: ps: this reminded me of the `is_ajax_request()` wrapper [proposal](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25669) by @toscho, that hopefully will make it through soon ;-)

Comment: probably want to add a status code so search engine indexes get updated.

Comment: do you need ajax checks for template redirects?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt but I can't imagine it would be needed either. Can't do a legitimate `template_redirect` with AJAX anyway as any JS would be too early ( or late depending on how you're looking at it ) in the WP load process.

Comment: I took a look at my debug events. `parse_request` & `template_redirect` don't seem to conflict with `wp_authenticate` and `wp_login`. But it makes me think `template_redirect` is too late.